# What is the purpose of double parentheses with file redirection?

Tags: bash, sh

I see this with the `partclone` command, for example

```
( ( partclone.restore -s ${SOUR_PART} -o ${DEST_PART} 2>&3 ) 3>&1 ) | ...
```

What is the meaning or purpose of `2>&3 ) 3>&1 )`?  Is it the same as

```
partclone.restore -s ${SOUR_PART} -o ${DEST_PART} 2>&1
```

...? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double open paren creates two sub shells.

The 2>&3 in the inner most shell sends stderr to file descriptor 3

The 3>&1 in the outer most shell sends file descriptor 3 to stdout, which is then piped to the next command.

See IO redirection in The Linux Documentation Project here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

and for a redirect script that will blow your mind, see the exercise here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
2>&3
```

Tells shell to redirect any output destined for file descriptor 2 (which is standard error) to file descriptor 3

```
3>&1
```

Says to redirect any I/O destined for file descriptor 3 to file descriptor 1 (standard output).

The parentheses help the shell parse it all out and create a subshell. The inside parentheses have:

```
( partclone.restore -s ${SOUR_PART} -o ${DEST_PART} 2>&3 )
```

Which indicates a particular redirection of I/O within that subshell. Then this is wrapped in another set of parentheses for another subshell with its own redirection:

```
( the_command_shown_above 3>&1 ) | ...
```

And all the standard output is then piped into whatever command is represented by `...`

One interesting use of this method is if you want to capture `stderr` rather than `stdin` with a command that normally only accepts `stdin`. Consider:

```
( (my_cmd 2>&1 1>&3) | error_processor ) 3>&1
```

This executes `my_cmd` and send its standard output to the terminal (ultimately) but routes the error output of `my_cmd` to the command `error_processor` which expects its input from `stdin`.

Comment: So is it the same as just using only 2>&1?

Comment: @user180574 the result will be the same, but the I/O will go through an extra level of redirection/buffering.

Comment: Is there any benefit? Why someone would use it?

Comment: @user180574 it would depend upon the internals of the command

Comment: The intent is probably to filter the error output but that part is omitted from this code fragment.

Comment: @user180574 I added an example

Answer (score 0):

It creates a subshell, which allows another step of redirection.